# Write gif loaded from glide to file

Tags: android, share, android-contentprovider, android-glide, android-file

Above question is root goal for sharing images which in process puts me to several issues in     Glide.
 I am using Glide 3.6 with retrofit 2 to fetch gif urls and loading them in   recyclerview.This is working fine but now i need to share the loaded image which requires me to save/write loaded gif in a file and there comes the problem :

1: I cant' save cached image to a file since it cache location is not very clear.

2: I am using listener which provides GlideGifDrawble as resource variable but how to write GlideGifdrawble to a file since binary data from gifdrawble will in turn will lead to static bitmap.

Code:

```
final File file=new    File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"images/images"+number+".Gif");
number++;

    holder.img_thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            {
                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(lm.get(position).getUrl())
                        .asGif()
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .crossFade()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GifDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GifDrawable>     target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, String model, Target<GifDrawable> target,
                                                           boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                BufferedOutputStream s ;
                                frames= resource.getFrameCount();
                                try {
                                    s = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                                    s.write(resource.getData());
                                    s.flush();
                                    s.close();
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Does the file created by "s.write(resource.getData))" not contain an animated GIF image?